# input field not displaying when checked each checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

1. I have two checkboxes.
2. The first one is already checked.
3. If the checkbox is checked, then display the input field(it is working).
4. When I check the other checkbox then the first checkbox should uncheck automatically(working).
5. The problem is when the first checkbox is unchecked, then the input field which is generated by first checkbox is not disappearing.

Could anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('#Experience').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
          var tb = $('<input type="number" name="totalyr" min="0" id="common" placeholder="Total Year Experience" class="form-control col-xs-3" required><input type="number" name="totalmn" min="0" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Total Month Experience" required><br><input type="text" name="currentjob" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Current Job Title" required><input type="text" name="currentjob" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Current Company Name" required><br><input type="number" id="common" name="rupee" min="0" class="form-control col-xs-3 fa fa-rupee" placeholder="Annual Salary ₹:" required>');
          $(this).after(tb)  ;
    }
    else if($(this).siblings('#common').length>0){
        $(this).siblings('#common').remove();
    }
})

/*Here for second field*/

$('#Fresher').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
          var tb = $('<input type="text" name="lookingfor" min="0" id="common" placeholder="Currently Looking For" class="form-control col-xs-3" required>');
          $(this).after(tb)  ;
    }
    else if($(this).siblings('#common').length>0){
        $(this).siblings('#common').remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" id="Fresher" name="" checked />
            <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" id="Experience" name="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Here u can see, if i select second checkbox then first checkbox generated input field is not disappearing

Comment: Your snippet's working and the description of your question do not match.

Comment: please check there if one checkbox is checked then another one is not automatically unchecking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('#Experience').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#Fresher").prop("checked", false);
        $("#Fresher").siblings('#common').remove();
        var tb = $('<input type="number" name="totalyr" min="0" id="common" placeholder="Total Year Experience" class="form-control col-xs-3" required><input type="number" name="totalmn" min="0" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Total Month Experience" required><br><input type="text" name="currentjob" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Current Job Title" required><input type="text" name="currentjob" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Current Company Name" required><br><input type="number" id="common" name="rupee" min="0" class="form-control col-xs-3 fa fa-rupee" placeholder="Annual Salary ₹:" required>');
        $(this).after(tb);          
    }
    else if($(this).siblings('#common').length>0){
        $(this).siblings('#common').remove();
    }
})

/*Here for second field*/

$('#Fresher').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#Experience").prop("checked", false);
        $("#Experience").siblings('#common').remove();
        var tb = $('<input type="text" name="lookingfor" min="0" id="common" placeholder="Currently Looking For" class="form-control col-xs-3" required>');
        $(this).after(tb);          
    }
    else if($(this).siblings('#common').length>0){
        $(this).siblings('#common').remove();
    }
});

$('#Fresher').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" id="Fresher" name="" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" id="Experience" name="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Below 2 lines are added in the `if` condition of `click()` function for `Experience`.

```
$("#Fresher").prop("checked", false);
$("#Fresher").siblings('#common').remove();
```

Below 2 lines are added in the `if` condition of `click()` function for `Fresher`.

```
$("#Experience").prop("checked", false);
$("#Experience").siblings('#common').remove();
```

To show the field for by default first checkbox just remove `checked` from the HTML input field and trigger `click` function for `Fresher`.

**Suggestions:** Please add the whole code in `ready()` function to avoid the issues on page load.

Comment: Its good but please can u make it by defualt first checkbox should checked as well as show input field.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$('#Experience').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
          var tb = $('<div id="experiencediv"><input type="number" name="totalyr" min="0" id="common" placeholder="Total Year Experience" class="form-control col-xs-3" required><input type="number" name="totalmn" min="0" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Total Month Experience" required><br><input type="text" name="currentjob" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Current Job Title" required><input type="text" name="currentjob" id="common" class="form-control col-xs-3" placeholder="Current Company Name" required><br><input type="number" id="common" name="rupee" min="0" class="form-control col-xs-3 fa fa-rupee" placeholder="Annual Salary ₹:" required></div>');
          $(this).after(tb);
           $('#Fresher').prop('checked', false);
           $('#fresherdiv').remove();
    }
    else {
        $('#experiencediv').remove();
    }
})

/*Here for second field*/

$('#Fresher').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
          var tb = $('<div id="fresherdiv"><input type="text" name="lookingfor" min="0" id="common" placeholder="Currently Looking For" class="form-control col-xs-3" required></div>');
          $(this).after(tb);
          $('#Experience').prop('checked', false);
           $('#experiencediv').remove();
    }
    else {
        $('#fresherdiv').remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" id="Fresher" name="" checked />
            <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" id="Experience" name="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: if one checkbox is checked then another one should unchecked with each generated field also can u do that.

Comment: @mdserver I have updated my coding. please check. if any problem please let me know.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt i knew bro but i tried so many time for this when didn't become possible by me then only i came here.